# letting long/many footnotes 'flow' over two pages (eledpar)

Tags: footnotes, eledmac, eledpar

I'm using the eledmac and eledpar packages for typesetting several critical editions. I have facing pages with the original foreign language on the left, even pages and the accompanying translation on the right, uneven pages.

The foreign text on the left pages has textual variants in the apparatus/footnote series, the translation has two separate series of footnotes with references and comments.

The problem now is that usually the translation and its footnotes take up lots of space while there is unused space on the left pages with the foreign text.
Is there a way to let the footnotes belonging to a right page begin on a left facing page and then flow over to the right page (in the lower space for footnotes) when the left page is full?

Here is a current minimal example with all the footnotes on the pages they 'belong' to:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}
\usepackage{setspace}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\onehalfspacing
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\footparagraph{A}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteA}{\alph{footnoteA}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering\pstart
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \edtext{consectetuer}{\Afootnote{insectetuer M}} adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum \edtext{sociis}{\Afootnote{socialis M}} natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, \edtext{vulputate}{\Afootnote{vultures}} eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum \edtext{felis}{\Afootnote{felidae D}} eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. \edtext{Aenean}{\Afootnote{Herculean T}} leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.

Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, \edtext{lorem}{\Afootnote{ipsum Q}}. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet \edtext{orci}{\Afootnote{Orcs S}} eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc.
\pend\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering\pstart
One morning, when Gregor Samsa\footnoteA{Obscure reference 1} woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly domed and divided by arches into stiff sections. The bedding\footnoteB{Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.} was hardly able to cover it and seemed ready to slide off any moment. His many legs, pitifully thin compared with the size of the rest of him, waved about helplessly as he looked. "What's happened to me?" he thought. It wasn't a dream. His room, a proper human room\footnoteB{One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen.} although a little too small, lay peacefully between its four familiar walls. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa\footnoteA{Obscure reference 2} was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather.

A wonderful serenity\footnoteB{Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.} has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the present moment; and yet I feel that I never was a greater artist than now. A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa\footnoteA{Obscure reference 3} was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and housed in a nice, gilded frame. It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. Gregor then turned to look out the window at the dull weather.
\pend\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\Pages

\end{pages}

\end{document}
```

In the end it should more like the pdf that is linked [here](http://www.fluxus-virus.com/en/what-critical.html). I was not sure if I'm allowed to link the pdfs of that website of professional typesetters here, hence the link.

I'm grateful for any ideas or suggestions.

Patrick

Comment: That is not how `eledmac/elecpar` is designed to work.  I'm pretty sure it would require a completely different implementation.

Comment: As maintener of eledpar, this question was also answer to me. Infortunatly, I found no way to manage it. It's a problem inside the way that TeX split the insert element. I ask a question on this forum, but I don't receipted answer. I think I can't implement this feature (and I would like to be able)...

Comment: I thought it would be difficult. Nevertheless thanks for the comments, jon and Maieul! Still, if anybody could think of a 'dirty' hack, I'm all ears. ;)

Comment: I am happy to say that I find a way ! There remains some several problem to solve (like : what should be the good height for a note in a side) but ... I hope to close these problem next week-end

Comment: Hi Maieul, that sounds wonderful! Please tell me/us when you're ready. Looking forward to it!

Comment: Hi, if you have a github account, could you post a message on https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/17 ?

Comment: I will post my try there. Actually, I have implemented for normal footnote. I have to try for paragraphed footnote, but is more complex. And I have an other issue in my to do list, and only week-end to take time on this problem.

Comment: So I have found a way. Contact me for test. I think it's ok, but ...

Answer (score 1):

The version 1.19.0-1.13.0 of eledmac/eledpar provides now this feature. I have just send it on CTAN.

You need to use `footnoteXnomk` to insert the notes of the series `X` in the left side, and `\footnoteXmk` to insert the mark of the note of the series `X` in the right side.

See this MWE

```
\begin{pages}

  \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
    \autopar

   Lorem\footnoteAnomk{A note called in right side, but printed in left side. A note called in right side, but printed in left side. A note called in right side, but printed in left side. A note called in right side, but printed in left side. A note called in right side, but printed in left side. A note called in right side, but printed in left side. A note called in right side, but printed in left side. A note called in right side, but printed in left side. A note called in right side, but printed in left side. A note called in right side, but printed in left side. A note called in right side, but printed in left side.} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus id erat imperdiet, sollicitudin tortor a, rhoncus ipsum. Aliquam at maximus nibh. Ut sed risus porttitor, eleifend tortor non, commodo nisl. Praesent eu ullamcorper est. Phasellus at eros eget ex feugiat scelerisque. 

    Vivamus et luctus justo. In aliquet, metus malesuada vestibulum ullamcorper, est sapien facilisis arcu, ac efficitur mi metus ac velit. Sed sagittis laoreet justo at iaculis. 

    Aliquam\footnoteAnomk{An other note called in right side, but printed in left side.  An other note called in right side, but printed in left side. An other note called in right side, but printed in left side. An other note called in right side, but printed in left side. An other note called in right side, but printed in left side. An other note called in right side, but printed in left side. An other note called in right side, but printed in left side.} eu erat id tellus bibendum semper eu eget nulla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nunc arcu, iaculis sit amet laoreet ut, finibus at nibh. 

    Curabitur non lacus eget tellus consectetur dignissim. Nullam a tempus enim. Donec ut pulvinar magna, in accumsan velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec lacinia scelerisque urna, sagittis fermentum est ultricies semper. 

    Aenean condimentum, leo vitae convallis porta, neque felis rhoncus metus, in iaculis nulla ligula vitae quam. Fusce at vehicula purus, id sollicitudin dolor. Maecenas scelerisque non est non luctus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent eu placerat urna. Donec fermentum mauris sit amet nulla semper lacinia. Donec eu ipsum ultricies, placerat odio id, ultrices urna. Cras id sapien ut nisi auctor elementum vel id tellus.

    \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \autopar
    Lorem\footnoteAmk ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus id erat imperdiet, sollicitudin tortor a, rhoncus ipsum. Aliquam at maximus nibh. Ut sed risus porttitor, eleifend tortor non, commodo nisl. Praesent eu ullamcorper est. Phasellus at eros eget ex feugiat scelerisque. Proin pellentesque lorem eu risus convallis consectetur ac molestie turpis. Maecenas blandit iaculis orci, et mattis dolor luctus vel. Praesent placerat varius tellus, nec convallis purus volutpat at. Vivamus sit amet est interdum, condimentum sem ultricies, posuere sapien. Maecenas vitae sapien diam. Donec et risus non nunc laoreet tincidunt. Pellentesque vehicula pellentesque sagittis. Morbi elementum tempus nunc, eu sodales erat convallis et. Maecenas condimentum pretium faucibus. Nam in ante nunc. Etiam lobortis, arcu a imperdiet interdum, felis erat mattis nunc, id posuere purus nisl a nibh.

    Vivamus et luctus justo. In aliquet, metus malesuada vestibulum ullamcorper, est sapien facilisis arcu, ac efficitur mi metus ac velit. Sed sagittis laoreet justo at iaculis. Morbi scelerisque nec quam eu efficitur. Integer nec massa ut lectus viverra ornare sed id libero. Praesent fermentum suscipit ante ut aliquam. Sed facilisis rutrum sapien vel blandit. Ut eget ex ut massa consequat sodales. Vestibulum venenatis in quam a molestie.

    Aliquam\footnoteAmk eu erat id tellus bibendum semper eu eget nulla. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin nunc arcu, iaculis sit amet laoreet ut, finibus at nibh. Aliquam vel nisl a sem pulvinar efficitur. Quisque dignissim, metus at consectetur ultrices, metus nunc ultrices quam, at ultrices dolor massa vitae urna. Nullam semper nisi dui, vel commodo mi lobortis sit amet. In non mattis orci. Integer aliquam dapibus convallis. Suspendisse sodales tincidunt ante quis laoreet. Etiam sodales mauris nulla, vitae mattis est consequat sit amet. Nam blandit rhoncus nisi. Sed accumsan, nibh non venenatis aliquam, dolor quam sodales turpis, nec aliquam nunc arcu quis urna.

    Curabitur non lacus eget tellus consectetur dignissim. Nullam a tempus enim. Donec ut pulvinar magna, in accumsan velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec lacinia scelerisque urna, sagittis fermentum est ultricies semper. Phasellus non augue ligula. Donec aliquet bibendum elit, quis tempor risus pulvinar id. Curabitur a cursus enim. Integer sit amet accumsan urna. Nam viverra at tortor ac gravida. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi imperdiet eleifend risus id consequat. Proin blandit mi a elit vehicula, a semper quam lacinia. Pellentesque at iaculis diam, quis condimentum justo. Nulla laoreet ut mauris sed tempor.

    Aenean condimentum, leo vitae convallis porta, neque felis rhoncus metus, in iaculis nulla ligula vitae quam. Fusce at vehicula purus, id sollicitudin dolor. Maecenas scelerisque non est non luctus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent eu placerat urna. Donec fermentum mauris sit amet nulla semper lacinia. 

    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}

\end{pages}
  \Pages
```