# Long footnote, newpage and output

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes, output-routine

In order to solve an issue in eledpar ([letting long/many footnotes 'flow' over two pages (eledpar)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141190/7712)), I need some help with the relation between insert, ouput and `\newpage`.

Let the (real) MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Before\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sit amet feugiat magna, vitae rutrum magna. Nam viverra lacus nec augue sodales, sed imperdiet quam egestas. Maecenas sed tellus in leo pellentesque ornare gravida vitae odio. Duis tristique suscipit porttitor. Nam vel ante lorem. Proin ornare euismod metus, nec auctor nisl pharetra eget. Curabitur fringilla erat ut ex varius, eget sagittis nunc pretium. Donec pulvinar cursus arcu non finibus. Pellentesque ut lorem et justo eleifend eleifend.
Pellentesque ac quam sed dolor maximus laoreet non at turpis. Mauris egestas leo elit. Morbi non venenatis ipsum. Sed id odio pulvinar, malesuada purus pharetra, viverra arcu. Mauris consectetur fermentum hendrerit. Nulla lacus arcu, dictum eu vehicula vitae, dignissim interdum risus. Donec convallis dolor ac sem faucibus, vitae porttitor neque lobortis. Pellentesque at tempor eros. Phasellus eget fringilla tellus, posuere porta enim. Sed pellentesque dolor ac feugiat feugiat. Nullam tempus lacus ut eros sagittis consectetur.
Cras rhoncus congue arcu, fringilla fringilla lorem rutrum viverra. Proin ultrices, felis vel efficitur gravida, lectus lectus suscipit lorem, nec condimentum risus odio quis lacus. Aliquam sem dolor, semper eget fringilla et, pellentesque ac nisl. Ut vitae finibus justo. Nulla lobortis semper tellus eget tempor. Phasellus rutrum ornare lacus a pulvinar. Proin sed odio in sem tincidunt convallis et id leo. Duis nec porta sapien. Sed lacinia erat non mauris fermentum, ac vulputate felis facilisis. Praesent pellentesque laoreet nulla ac convallis. Phasellus sed congue elit, in fermentum est. Nam nisl diam, suscipit eget eleifend nec, lacinia in ipsum. Etiam quis augue ut felis semper gravida vel eget ligula. Quisque quis leo quis leo blandit consequat. Fusce vel sapien ut urna varius tincidunt et eu ipsum.
Phasellus in tortor at diam euismod dignissim vitae in ex. Maecenas vestibulum rutrum enim, ut convallis felis accumsan vitae. Aenean id erat at nibh pretium aliquet sed ut purus. Nulla vel justo euismod, molestie metus nec, luctus urna. Fusce fermentum mattis enim eu viverra. Donec convallis, tellus ac congue pharetra, neque neque faucibus mi, sed scelerisque orci velit sit amet nisl. Sed eleifend eu eros quis blandit.
Etiam rhoncus rutrum ante eu ultricies. Morbi arcu dui, aliquet eu ante at, elementum aliquet tellus. Sed eget sodales lacus. Etiam venenatis sollicitudin mi, quis egestas mauris vulputate ut. Maecenas lobortis erat a lacus congue bibendum. Vestibulum interdum semper orci, sit amet mattis dui egestas non. Integer malesuada risus ut vehicula viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur maximus eget dui sed bibendum. Phasellus tristique arcu at metus rhoncus pretium.
Proin volutpat felis lobortis massa semper, ut efficitur est commodo. Nam dapibus metus vitae finibus hendrerit. Maecenas sit amet malesuada libero. Duis sed nisl vitae urna blandit placerat a ac eros. In pellentesque porttitor lacus sit amet mollis. Nulla facilisi. Aenean scelerisque neque pretium orci egestas, vel iaculis dolor ullamcorper.
Fusce hendrerit blandit ipsum quis scelerisque. Quisque ac tincidunt eros, vitae mattis diam. Nunc varius fringilla nisl, nec cursus erat hendrerit nec. Pellentesque volutpat lacus lectus, sed suscipit sem lacinia id. Nulla eget varius ex. Nullam ac justo ac nisi molestie mattis. Nunc a consectetur quam. Donec sit amet lacus massa.
Quisque commodo nunc a hendrerit pretium. Donec rhoncus, eros a ullamcorper blandit, mauris tellus tincidunt lacus, et dictum ligula risus at orci. In ornare, mauris vel efficitur facilisis, velit elit laoreet ante, et dignissim magna eros in ex. Nam varius hendrerit tempor. Maecenas quis augue augue. Integer bibendum, orci a sagittis dignissim, elit tortor fermentum augue, sed gravida magna ligula sed nisi. Cras suscipit justo nunc, eu mattis turpis vulputate at. Nulla facilisi. Nunc rutrum, enim non laoreet pellentesque, quam neque posuere tortor, nec placerat tellus est id purus. Aenean velit tellus, placerat maximus pellentesque in, viverra sit amet nunc. Donec aliquam nunc ligula, eget aliquam lorem mattis sit amet. Pellentesque in ultrices nisi. Donec iaculis dictum auctor. Aenean nulla sapien, sodales vel pharetra a, varius sit amet elit.
Maecenas et sagittis mauris. Donec nec urna nulla. Donec diam urna, bibendum sit amet sapien convallis, commodo sollicitudin mauris. Etiam et malesuada justo. In molestie tortor at massa tempor, vitae imperdiet neque sollicitudin. Donec id ultricies lectus, nec interdum nibh. Donec porttitor diam a nibh luctus scelerisque. Vestibulum tortor dolor, consectetur vitae metus sed, suscipit pulvinar lacus. Fusce id posuere diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec malesuada, nisl ac dapibus volutpat, elit turpis imperdiet urna, eget dictum ipsum elit ac felis. Nunc et suscipit nulla. Nunc tristique varius elementum. In consequat pharetra suscipit. Suspendisse potenti.
Quisque tincidunt risus eros, in congue nunc efficitur in. Etiam lobortis lectus et justo rhoncus, sit amet aliquam lorem rhoncus. In molestie, turpis eget dapibus hendrerit, turpis ipsum mattis sem, at finibus lectus odio sed arcu. Cras suscipit lacinia felis nec lobortis. Etiam non tempor nulla. Integer porttitor augue leo, at cursus mi sodales nec. Nulla facilisi. Praesent nulla purus, ultricies non libero et, condimentum porta turpis. Vestibulum tincidunt, magna et consequat viverra, arcu neque tristique ipsum, sed tincidunt nisi neque non mi.
Etiam sit amet sagittis magna, at faucibus nunc. Cras metus tortor, egestas et enim sit amet, pellentesque dictum mi. Nullam ultricies lorem non accumsan condimentum. Nulla sed dignissim augue. Vestibulum ornare ac mi vel efficitur. In nec leo elit. Aliquam sit amet ipsum ac metus semper consectetur. Etiam efficitur nisi in maximus convallis. Sed ac pretium eros, consectetur tincidunt nisl.
Nulla tincidunt malesuada odio eu posuere. Donec varius lacus ut tellus commodo porta. Nam convallis dui id tortor tristique, ut scelerisque lacus fringilla. Praesent non purus sed nisi auctor ornare quis sit amet ante. Praesent sit amet gravida est, at pellentesque ligula. Integer aliquam tempor ligula. Suspendisse blandit fermentum leo, quis posuere eros vulputate nec. Aliquam erat volutpat. In in orci vestibulum, feugiat est at, suscipit leo.
Fusce ultrices nisl quis sapien cursus, mattis mattis mi sodales. Morbi pulvinar, enim et facilisis tristique, ligula nisl iaculis purus, sit amet euismod ex urna nec neque. Praesent id velit elementum, finibus nisl quis, sollicitudin urna. Nunc porta auctor elit, id pulvinar mauris efficitur et. Morbi quis erat sed metus sagittis mattis vel ut erat. Donec eget aliquet sem, ac dictum purus. Donec varius risus et tortor pharetra, sed tincidunt erat viverra. Pellentesque accumsan dui ac rutrum dictum.
Phasellus aliquam lorem sit amet ex tempor aliquet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis sit amet faucibus sem, rhoncus semper lacus. Sed a eros diam. Curabitur sit amet ante elementum, suscipit tortor vitae, malesuada mi. Sed ac gravida mi. Mauris mollis nunc id lectus cursus, vel ornare justo aliquam. Pellentesque sed est metus. Nulla laoreet, augue in maximus accumsan, ante est gravida nisl, quis dignissim quam est scelerisque sem. Morbi ac purus metus. Duis ut tellus purus. Nunc at nisi luctus, pharetra nisi ac, vulputate enim. Praesent commodo finibus malesuada. Praesent non tortor fermentum, volutpat magna id, hendrerit tortor. In dolor lacus, imperdiet sit amet aliquam nec, ultrices sed sem.
Pellentesque quis lectus vitae elit rhoncus efficitur. Quisque tristique id tortor quis euismod. Etiam vitae neque quis quam feugiat porta at sit amet leo. Nam id leo vestibulum libero eleifend facilisis quis et orci. Vivamus vitae magna eu nibh facilisis auctor vitae sed purus. Curabitur a velit quis erat ullamcorper venenatis vitae non sem. Cras bibendum magna nec tellus convallis, in tincidunt justo auctor. Curabitur nec sem nibh. Vestibulum rhoncus laoreet nisi, sit amet rutrum lectus dictum id. Sed leo neque, iaculis viverra porta at, rhoncus eu felis. Mauris ornare arcu sit amet augue sagittis semper. Suspendisse egestas blandit lorem in posuere. Nam volutpat dolor at mauris malesuada, eget egestas orci gravida. Suspendisse dapibus felis sit amet sapien auctor, a sagittis ante sollicitudin. Vivamus a orci mollis, auctor lectus et, sodales nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
Donec in nunc luctus, iaculis sem id, tincidunt lorem. Donec congue consectetur ex, nec pretium arcu porta vel. Aliquam egestas massa non facilisis vulputate. Fusce viverra sit amet ligula quis lobortis. Etiam vulputate augue non nulla egestas commodo. Pellentesque pellentesque, nulla a efficitur pretium, turpis dolor convallis nibh, in pulvinar massa tellus sed felis. Fusce ac libero ac tellus vehicula tempus.
Donec facilisis, magna ac sagittis suscipit, libero lacus ultricies nibh, et ultrices risus tortor eget mauris. Aliquam sit amet cursus elit. Proin bibendum enim erat, ac aliquet elit dignissim a. Proin eu dolor dui. Vestibulum sodales risus eget interdum mollis. Curabitur semper tortor ultrices elit scelerisque auctor. Integer gravida consectetur leo, et cursus tellus faucibus consectetur. Phasellus non massa nec sem fermentum viverra vel quis risus. Donec lobortis tempor metus. Cras dapibus nulla semper sapien lobortis tempus. Quisque suscipit at nulla sed dictum. Duis aliquam enim nec lorem tristique, quis mattis ante vestibulum.
Sed sit amet sem nunc. Vivamus ornare sapien eu ligula efficitur accumsan. Ut in porttitor massa. Mauris pharetra tortor auctor nisl bibendum, nec mollis neque consectetur. Aliquam dictum non velit et bibendum. Aenean interdum magna quis libero gravida volutpat. Sed at dolor a nisl blandit vehicula. Morbi viverra orci justo, ut maximus ligula porta eget. Duis finibus velit odio, sit amet venenatis lectus vestibulum ac. Duis vitae nisl quis nisi suscipit laoreet at at ipsum. Nulla eleifend porttitor ullamcorper.
Sed imperdiet facilisis eleifend. Ut quis quam venenatis enim dictum maximus sit amet id mi. Curabitur a nisl ut lorem ornare viverra. Cras diam justo, consequat ac sapien eget, scelerisque viverra mi. Suspendisse ac justo vel lacus malesuada vestibulum et eget elit. Aliquam pulvinar ultricies ipsum. Pellentesque nisi ligula, efficitur ut urna vel, efficitur maximus augue. Integer placerat a nibh vitae scelerisque.
Nam non lectus risus. Aliquam a diam a justo ultrices vestibulum ut ac erat. Mauris efficitur, neque eget euismod bibendum, orci turpis suscipit turpis, ut finibus leo risus nec est. Vestibulum imperdiet arcu in hendrerit molestie. Etiam eget nunc libero. Donec viverra mauris a condimentum cursus. Sed tortor risus, porta ac lacus quis, placerat aliquam nibh. Donec lorem elit, congue at velit congue, ullamcorper ullamcorper lacus. Sed pretium sit amet ipsum tincidunt tempus. Nullam eu tempus nulla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
}
\newpage
After
\end{document}
```

With the default output routine of LaTeX, by page is printed:

1. "Before" + first part of the long note.
2. 2nd part of the long note.
3. "After" Third part of the long note.

I try, but I am not able, to modify the output routine to obtain:

1. "Before"+ first part of the long note.
2. "After" + 2nd part of the long note.
3. Third part of the long note.

My contraints are:

1. Not modify the space kept for note.
2. Not shortening the note.
3. Keep the `\newpage` (because it's for debugging eledpar!)
4. Don't depend of some test about the size of the text on first and second page

Actually, what I does it: before each insert, look for the available place in the insert, cut the too long insert and kept then in a box, not in TeX insert. At the end of each page, after voiding the insert, add the content of this box as a new insert, for the next page. But it's dirty, I have to imitate the TeX insert mechanism. Not good.

So I think the only good way is the modify the output routine, but I don't find any solution.

Comment: I substituted `\newpage` by `\vfil\break` and `\footnote` by `\footnote*` and I tried to run this in plain TeX. The word "After" is at the second page as you wish. This implies that your problem is LaTeX specific and one of the solution of this problem is: don't use LaTeX.

Comment: it's not possible in my case ;-)

Comment: but indeed, it's specific to LaTeX. So I have to look for it...

Comment: it's not possible in my case, as it's for debugin eledpar package, which is a LaTeX package.

Comment: @wipet I assume your "solution" was intended as a joke, but changing format rather than just setting one insert register seems a bit drastic.

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
\dimen\footins=\dimexpr\textheight-2\baselineskip\relax% or <num>\baselineskip
```

or

```
\dimen\footins=10cm
```

code complete

```
\documentclass{article}
\dimen\footins=\dimexpr\textheight-2\baselineskip\relax
\begin{document}
Before\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sit amet feugiat magna, vitae rutrum magna. Nam viverra lacus nec augue sodales, sed imperdiet quam egestas. Maecenas sed tellus in leo pellentesque ornare gravida vitae odio. Duis tristique suscipit porttitor. Nam vel ante lorem. Proin ornare euismod metus, nec auctor nisl pharetra eget. Curabitur fringilla erat ut ex varius, eget sagittis nunc pretium. Donec pulvinar cursus arcu non finibus. Pellentesque ut lorem et justo eleifend eleifend.
Pellentesque ac quam sed dolor maximus laoreet non at turpis. Mauris egestas leo elit. Morbi non venenatis ipsum. Sed id odio pulvinar, malesuada purus pharetra, viverra arcu. Mauris consectetur fermentum hendrerit. Nulla lacus arcu, dictum eu vehicula vitae, dignissim interdum risus. Donec convallis dolor ac sem faucibus, vitae porttitor neque lobortis. Pellentesque at tempor eros. Phasellus eget fringilla tellus, posuere porta enim. Sed pellentesque dolor ac feugiat feugiat. Nullam tempus lacus ut eros sagittis consectetur.
Cras rhoncus congue arcu, fringilla fringilla lorem rutrum viverra. Proin ultrices, felis vel efficitur gravida, lectus lectus suscipit lorem, nec condimentum risus odio quis lacus. Aliquam sem dolor, semper eget fringilla et, pellentesque ac nisl. Ut vitae finibus justo. Nulla lobortis semper tellus eget tempor. Phasellus rutrum ornare lacus a pulvinar. Proin sed odio in sem tincidunt convallis et id leo. Duis nec porta sapien. Sed lacinia erat non mauris fermentum, ac vulputate felis facilisis. Praesent pellentesque laoreet nulla ac convallis. Phasellus sed congue elit, in fermentum est. Nam nisl diam, suscipit eget eleifend nec, lacinia in ipsum. Etiam quis augue ut felis semper gravida vel eget ligula. Quisque quis leo quis leo blandit consequat. Fusce vel sapien ut urna varius tincidunt et eu ipsum.
Phasellus in tortor at diam euismod dignissim vitae in ex. Maecenas vestibulum rutrum enim, ut convallis felis accumsan vitae. Aenean id erat at nibh pretium aliquet sed ut purus. Nulla vel justo euismod, molestie metus nec, luctus urna. Fusce fermentum mattis enim eu viverra. Donec convallis, tellus ac congue pharetra, neque neque faucibus mi, sed scelerisque orci velit sit amet nisl. Sed eleifend eu eros quis blandit.
Etiam rhoncus rutrum ante eu ultricies. Morbi arcu dui, aliquet eu ante at, elementum aliquet tellus. Sed eget sodales lacus. Etiam venenatis sollicitudin mi, quis egestas mauris vulputate ut. Maecenas lobortis erat a lacus congue bibendum. Vestibulum interdum semper orci, sit amet mattis dui egestas non. Integer malesuada risus ut vehicula viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur maximus eget dui sed bibendum. Phasellus tristique arcu at metus rhoncus pretium.
Proin volutpat felis lobortis massa semper, ut efficitur est commodo. Nam dapibus metus vitae finibus hendrerit. Maecenas sit amet malesuada libero. Duis sed nisl vitae urna blandit placerat a ac eros. In pellentesque porttitor lacus sit amet mollis. Nulla facilisi. Aenean scelerisque neque pretium orci egestas, vel iaculis dolor ullamcorper.
Fusce hendrerit blandit ipsum quis scelerisque. Quisque ac tincidunt eros, vitae mattis diam. Nunc varius fringilla nisl, nec cursus erat hendrerit nec. Pellentesque volutpat lacus lectus, sed suscipit sem lacinia id. Nulla eget varius ex. Nullam ac justo ac nisi molestie mattis. Nunc a consectetur quam. Donec sit amet lacus massa.
Quisque commodo nunc a hendrerit pretium. Donec rhoncus, eros a ullamcorper blandit, mauris tellus tincidunt lacus, et dictum ligula risus at orci. In ornare, mauris vel efficitur facilisis, velit elit laoreet ante, et dignissim magna eros in ex. Nam varius hendrerit tempor. Maecenas quis augue augue. Integer bibendum, orci a sagittis dignissim, elit tortor fermentum augue, sed gravida magna ligula sed nisi. Cras suscipit justo nunc, eu mattis turpis vulputate at. Nulla facilisi. Nunc rutrum, enim non laoreet pellentesque, quam neque posuere tortor, nec placerat tellus est id purus. Aenean velit tellus, placerat maximus pellentesque in, viverra sit amet nunc. Donec aliquam nunc ligula, eget aliquam lorem mattis sit amet. Pellentesque in ultrices nisi. Donec iaculis dictum auctor. Aenean nulla sapien, sodales vel pharetra a, varius sit amet elit.
Maecenas et sagittis mauris. Donec nec urna nulla. Donec diam urna, bibendum sit amet sapien convallis, commodo sollicitudin mauris. Etiam et malesuada justo. In molestie tortor at massa tempor, vitae imperdiet neque sollicitudin. Donec id ultricies lectus, nec interdum nibh. Donec porttitor diam a nibh luctus scelerisque. Vestibulum tortor dolor, consectetur vitae metus sed, suscipit pulvinar lacus. Fusce id posuere diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec malesuada, nisl ac dapibus volutpat, elit turpis imperdiet urna, eget dictum ipsum elit ac felis. Nunc et suscipit nulla. Nunc tristique varius elementum. In consequat pharetra suscipit. Suspendisse potenti.
Quisque tincidunt risus eros, in congue nunc efficitur in. Etiam lobortis lectus et justo rhoncus, sit amet aliquam lorem rhoncus. In molestie, turpis eget dapibus hendrerit, turpis ipsum mattis sem, at finibus lectus odio sed arcu. Cras suscipit lacinia felis nec lobortis. Etiam non tempor nulla. Integer porttitor augue leo, at cursus mi sodales nec. Nulla facilisi. Praesent nulla purus, ultricies non libero et, condimentum porta turpis. Vestibulum tincidunt, magna et consequat viverra, arcu neque tristique ipsum, sed tincidunt nisi neque non mi.
Etiam sit amet sagittis magna, at faucibus nunc. Cras metus tortor, egestas et enim sit amet, pellentesque dictum mi. Nullam ultricies lorem non accumsan condimentum. Nulla sed dignissim augue. Vestibulum ornare ac mi vel efficitur. In nec leo elit. Aliquam sit amet ipsum ac metus semper consectetur. Etiam efficitur nisi in maximus convallis. Sed ac pretium eros, consectetur tincidunt nisl.
Nulla tincidunt malesuada odio eu posuere. Donec varius lacus ut tellus commodo porta. Nam convallis dui id tortor tristique, ut scelerisque lacus fringilla. Praesent non purus sed nisi auctor ornare quis sit amet ante. Praesent sit amet gravida est, at pellentesque ligula. Integer aliquam tempor ligula. Suspendisse blandit fermentum leo, quis posuere eros vulputate nec. Aliquam erat volutpat. In in orci vestibulum, feugiat est at, suscipit leo.
Fusce ultrices nisl quis sapien cursus, mattis mattis mi sodales. Morbi pulvinar, enim et facilisis tristique, ligula nisl iaculis purus, sit amet euismod ex urna nec neque. Praesent id velit elementum, finibus nisl quis, sollicitudin urna. Nunc porta auctor elit, id pulvinar mauris efficitur et. Morbi quis erat sed metus sagittis mattis vel ut erat. Donec eget aliquet sem, ac dictum purus. Donec varius risus et tortor pharetra, sed tincidunt erat viverra. Pellentesque accumsan dui ac rutrum dictum.
Phasellus aliquam lorem sit amet ex tempor aliquet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis sit amet faucibus sem, rhoncus semper lacus. Sed a eros diam. Curabitur sit amet ante elementum, suscipit tortor vitae, malesuada mi. Sed ac gravida mi. Mauris mollis nunc id lectus cursus, vel ornare justo aliquam. Pellentesque sed est metus. Nulla laoreet, augue in maximus accumsan, ante est gravida nisl, quis dignissim quam est scelerisque sem. Morbi ac purus metus. Duis ut tellus purus. Nunc at nisi luctus, pharetra nisi ac, vulputate enim. Praesent commodo finibus malesuada. Praesent non tortor fermentum, volutpat magna id, hendrerit tortor. In dolor lacus, imperdiet sit amet aliquam nec, ultrices sed sem.
Pellentesque quis lectus vitae elit rhoncus efficitur. Quisque tristique id tortor quis euismod. Etiam vitae neque quis quam feugiat porta at sit amet leo. Nam id leo vestibulum libero eleifend facilisis quis et orci. Vivamus vitae magna eu nibh facilisis auctor vitae sed purus. Curabitur a velit quis erat ullamcorper venenatis vitae non sem. Cras bibendum magna nec tellus convallis, in tincidunt justo auctor. Curabitur nec sem nibh. Vestibulum rhoncus laoreet nisi, sit amet rutrum lectus dictum id. Sed leo neque, iaculis viverra porta at, rhoncus eu felis. Mauris ornare arcu sit amet augue sagittis semper. Suspendisse egestas blandit lorem in posuere. Nam volutpat dolor at mauris malesuada, eget egestas orci gravida. Suspendisse dapibus felis sit amet sapien auctor, a sagittis ante sollicitudin. Vivamus a orci mollis, auctor lectus et, sodales nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
Donec in nunc luctus, iaculis sem id, tincidunt lorem. Donec congue consectetur ex, nec pretium arcu porta vel. Aliquam egestas massa non facilisis vulputate. Fusce viverra sit amet ligula quis lobortis. Etiam vulputate augue non nulla egestas commodo. Pellentesque pellentesque, nulla a efficitur pretium, turpis dolor convallis nibh, in pulvinar massa tellus sed felis. Fusce ac libero ac tellus vehicula tempus.
Donec facilisis, magna ac sagittis suscipit, libero lacus ultricies nibh, et ultrices risus tortor eget mauris. Aliquam sit amet cursus elit. Proin bibendum enim erat, ac aliquet elit dignissim a. Proin eu dolor dui. Vestibulum sodales risus eget interdum mollis. Curabitur semper tortor ultrices elit scelerisque auctor. Integer gravida consectetur leo, et cursus tellus faucibus consectetur. Phasellus non massa nec sem fermentum viverra vel quis risus. Donec lobortis tempor metus. Cras dapibus nulla semper sapien lobortis tempus. Quisque suscipit at nulla sed dictum. Duis aliquam enim nec lorem tristique, quis mattis ante vestibulum.
Sed sit amet sem nunc. Vivamus ornare sapien eu ligula efficitur accumsan. Ut in porttitor massa. Mauris pharetra tortor auctor nisl bibendum, nec mollis neque consectetur. Aliquam dictum non velit et bibendum. Aenean interdum magna quis libero gravida volutpat. Sed at dolor a nisl blandit vehicula. Morbi viverra orci justo, ut maximus ligula porta eget. Duis finibus velit odio, sit amet venenatis lectus vestibulum ac. Duis vitae nisl quis nisi suscipit laoreet at at ipsum. Nulla eleifend porttitor ullamcorper.
Sed imperdiet facilisis eleifend. Ut quis quam venenatis enim dictum maximus sit amet id mi. Curabitur a nisl ut lorem ornare viverra. Cras diam justo, consequat ac sapien eget, scelerisque viverra mi. Suspendisse ac justo vel lacus malesuada vestibulum et eget elit. Aliquam pulvinar ultricies ipsum. Pellentesque nisi ligula, efficitur ut urna vel, efficitur maximus augue. Integer placerat a nibh vitae scelerisque.
Nam non lectus risus. Aliquam a diam a justo ultrices vestibulum ut ac erat. Mauris efficitur, neque eget euismod bibendum, orci turpis suscipit turpis, ut finibus leo risus nec est. Vestibulum imperdiet arcu in hendrerit molestie. Etiam eget nunc libero. Donec viverra mauris a condimentum cursus. Sed tortor risus, porta ac lacus quis, placerat aliquam nibh. Donec lorem elit, congue at velit congue, ullamcorper ullamcorper lacus. Sed pretium sit amet ipsum tincidunt tempus. Nullam eu tempus nulla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
}

After
\end{document}
```

you don't need

```
\newpage
```

Comment: read my contraint 1. :Not modify the space kept for note.

Comment: As I have explained, it's to debug a package, where the \newpage is needed. I need it (it will be complex to explain why, but I need)

Comment: OK. But we (or latex) need to know how many text in the second page 1,2 or 3 ... lines. Like float object \textfraction=

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your remark. I suppose that only p. 1 and p. 2 has text. p. 1 is "before" p. 2 is "after". next page ... are empty.

Comment: yes i mean how long is the text after, just word after ,1 line or a paragraph. latex need to know a dimen to reserve  for text.

Comment: hum, what are you thinking ? it could be 1 line, one paragraph, one page...

Comment: +1 I just updated my answer and now realise it is same as this.

Comment: @Maïeul Your first comment is wrong, this (if you just subtract 1 baselineskip) isn't reducing the space for notes except in the one case that the entire page is given to notes which is exactly the case that you want to avoid.

Comment: ok, my mwe was not good, my problem was not this, so all is solved.

Answer (score 4):

here you can just prevent a full page of footnotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\dimen\footins\dimexpr\textheight-\baselineskip\relax
\begin{document}
Before\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sit amet feugiat magna, vitae rutrum magna. Nam viverra lacus nec augue sodales, sed imperdiet quam egestas. Maecenas sed tellus in leo pellentesque ornare gravida vitae odio. Duis tristique suscipit porttitor. Nam vel ante lorem. Proin ornare euismod metus, nec auctor nisl pharetra eget. Curabitur fringilla erat ut ex varius, eget sagittis nunc pretium. Donec pulvinar cursus arcu non finibus. Pellentesque ut lorem et justo eleifend eleifend.
Pellentesque ac quam sed dolor maximus laoreet non at turpis. Mauris egestas leo elit. Morbi non venenatis ipsum. Sed id odio pulvinar, malesuada purus pharetra, viverra arcu. Mauris consectetur fermentum hendrerit. Nulla lacus arcu, dictum eu vehicula vitae, dignissim interdum risus. Donec convallis dolor ac sem faucibus, vitae porttitor neque lobortis. Pellentesque at tempor eros. Phasellus eget fringilla tellus, posuere porta enim. Sed pellentesque dolor ac feugiat feugiat. Nullam tempus lacus ut eros sagittis consectetur.
Cras rhoncus congue arcu, fringilla fringilla lorem rutrum viverra. Proin ultrices, felis vel efficitur gravida, lectus lectus suscipit lorem, nec condimentum risus odio quis lacus. Aliquam sem dolor, semper eget fringilla et, pellentesque ac nisl. Ut vitae finibus justo. Nulla lobortis semper tellus eget tempor. Phasellus rutrum ornare lacus a pulvinar. Proin sed odio in sem tincidunt convallis et id leo. Duis nec porta sapien. Sed lacinia erat non mauris fermentum, ac vulputate felis facilisis. Praesent pellentesque laoreet nulla ac convallis. Phasellus sed congue elit, in fermentum est. Nam nisl diam, suscipit eget eleifend nec, lacinia in ipsum. Etiam quis augue ut felis semper gravida vel eget ligula. Quisque quis leo quis leo blandit consequat. Fusce vel sapien ut urna varius tincidunt et eu ipsum.
Phasellus in tortor at diam euismod dignissim vitae in ex. Maecenas vestibulum rutrum enim, ut convallis felis accumsan vitae. Aenean id erat at nibh pretium aliquet sed ut purus. Nulla vel justo euismod, molestie metus nec, luctus urna. Fusce fermentum mattis enim eu viverra. Donec convallis, tellus ac congue pharetra, neque neque faucibus mi, sed scelerisque orci velit sit amet nisl. Sed eleifend eu eros quis blandit.
Etiam rhoncus rutrum ante eu ultricies. Morbi arcu dui, aliquet eu ante at, elementum aliquet tellus. Sed eget sodales lacus. Etiam venenatis sollicitudin mi, quis egestas mauris vulputate ut. Maecenas lobortis erat a lacus congue bibendum. Vestibulum interdum semper orci, sit amet mattis dui egestas non. Integer malesuada risus ut vehicula viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur maximus eget dui sed bibendum. Phasellus tristique arcu at metus rhoncus pretium.
Proin volutpat felis lobortis massa semper, ut efficitur est commodo. Nam dapibus metus vitae finibus hendrerit. Maecenas sit amet malesuada libero. Duis sed nisl vitae urna blandit placerat a ac eros. In pellentesque porttitor lacus sit amet mollis. Nulla facilisi. Aenean scelerisque neque pretium orci egestas, vel iaculis dolor ullamcorper.
Fusce hendrerit blandit ipsum quis scelerisque. Quisque ac tincidunt eros, vitae mattis diam. Nunc varius fringilla nisl, nec cursus erat hendrerit nec. Pellentesque volutpat lacus lectus, sed suscipit sem lacinia id. Nulla eget varius ex. Nullam ac justo ac nisi molestie mattis. Nunc a consectetur quam. Donec sit amet lacus massa.
Quisque commodo nunc a hendrerit pretium. Donec rhoncus, eros a ullamcorper blandit, mauris tellus tincidunt lacus, et dictum ligula risus at orci. In ornare, mauris vel efficitur facilisis, velit elit laoreet ante, et dignissim magna eros in ex. Nam varius hendrerit tempor. Maecenas quis augue augue. Integer bibendum, orci a sagittis dignissim, elit tortor fermentum augue, sed gravida magna ligula sed nisi. Cras suscipit justo nunc, eu mattis turpis vulputate at. Nulla facilisi. Nunc rutrum, enim non laoreet pellentesque, quam neque posuere tortor, nec placerat tellus est id purus. Aenean velit tellus, placerat maximus pellentesque in, viverra sit amet nunc. Donec aliquam nunc ligula, eget aliquam lorem mattis sit amet. Pellentesque in ultrices nisi. Donec iaculis dictum auctor. Aenean nulla sapien, sodales vel pharetra a, varius sit amet elit.
Maecenas et sagittis mauris. Donec nec urna nulla. Donec diam urna, bibendum sit amet sapien convallis, commodo sollicitudin mauris. Etiam et malesuada justo. In molestie tortor at massa tempor, vitae imperdiet neque sollicitudin. Donec id ultricies lectus, nec interdum nibh. Donec porttitor diam a nibh luctus scelerisque. Vestibulum tortor dolor, consectetur vitae metus sed, suscipit pulvinar lacus. Fusce id posuere diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec malesuada, nisl ac dapibus volutpat, elit turpis imperdiet urna, eget dictum ipsum elit ac felis. Nunc et suscipit nulla. Nunc tristique varius elementum. In consequat pharetra suscipit. Suspendisse potenti.
Quisque tincidunt risus eros, in congue nunc efficitur in. Etiam lobortis lectus et justo rhoncus, sit amet aliquam lorem rhoncus. In molestie, turpis eget dapibus hendrerit, turpis ipsum mattis sem, at finibus lectus odio sed arcu. Cras suscipit lacinia felis nec lobortis. Etiam non tempor nulla. Integer porttitor augue leo, at cursus mi sodales nec. Nulla facilisi. Praesent nulla purus, ultricies non libero et, condimentum porta turpis. Vestibulum tincidunt, magna et consequat viverra, arcu neque tristique ipsum, sed tincidunt nisi neque non mi.
Etiam sit amet sagittis magna, at faucibus nunc. Cras metus tortor, egestas et enim sit amet, pellentesque dictum mi. Nullam ultricies lorem non accumsan condimentum. Nulla sed dignissim augue. Vestibulum ornare ac mi vel efficitur. In nec leo elit. Aliquam sit amet ipsum ac metus semper consectetur. Etiam efficitur nisi in maximus convallis. Sed ac pretium eros, consectetur tincidunt nisl.
Nulla tincidunt malesuada odio eu posuere. Donec varius lacus ut tellus commodo porta. Nam convallis dui id tortor tristique, ut scelerisque lacus fringilla. Praesent non purus sed nisi auctor ornare quis sit amet ante. Praesent sit amet gravida est, at pellentesque ligula. Integer aliquam tempor ligula. Suspendisse blandit fermentum leo, quis posuere eros vulputate nec. Aliquam erat volutpat. In in orci vestibulum, feugiat est at, suscipit leo.
Fusce ultrices nisl quis sapien cursus, mattis mattis mi sodales. Morbi pulvinar, enim et facilisis tristique, ligula nisl iaculis purus, sit amet euismod ex urna nec neque. Praesent id velit elementum, finibus nisl quis, sollicitudin urna. Nunc porta auctor elit, id pulvinar mauris efficitur et. Morbi quis erat sed metus sagittis mattis vel ut erat. Donec eget aliquet sem, ac dictum purus. Donec varius risus et tortor pharetra, sed tincidunt erat viverra. Pellentesque accumsan dui ac rutrum dictum.
Phasellus aliquam lorem sit amet ex tempor aliquet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis sit amet faucibus sem, rhoncus semper lacus. Sed a eros diam. Curabitur sit amet ante elementum, suscipit tortor vitae, malesuada mi. Sed ac gravida mi. Mauris mollis nunc id lectus cursus, vel ornare justo aliquam. Pellentesque sed est metus. Nulla laoreet, augue in maximus accumsan, ante est gravida nisl, quis dignissim quam est scelerisque sem. Morbi ac purus metus. Duis ut tellus purus. Nunc at nisi luctus, pharetra nisi ac, vulputate enim. Praesent commodo finibus malesuada. Praesent non tortor fermentum, volutpat magna id, hendrerit tortor. In dolor lacus, imperdiet sit amet aliquam nec, ultrices sed sem.
Pellentesque quis lectus vitae elit rhoncus efficitur. Quisque tristique id tortor quis euismod. Etiam vitae neque quis quam feugiat porta at sit amet leo. Nam id leo vestibulum libero eleifend facilisis quis et orci. Vivamus vitae magna eu nibh facilisis auctor vitae sed purus. Curabitur a velit quis erat ullamcorper venenatis vitae non sem. Cras bibendum magna nec tellus convallis, in tincidunt justo auctor. Curabitur nec sem nibh. Vestibulum rhoncus laoreet nisi, sit amet rutrum lectus dictum id. Sed leo neque, iaculis viverra porta at, rhoncus eu felis. Mauris ornare arcu sit amet augue sagittis semper. Suspendisse egestas blandit lorem in posuere. Nam volutpat dolor at mauris malesuada, eget egestas orci gravida. Suspendisse dapibus felis sit amet sapien auctor, a sagittis ante sollicitudin. Vivamus a orci mollis, auctor lectus et, sodales nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
Donec in nunc luctus, iaculis sem id, tincidunt lorem. Donec congue consectetur ex, nec pretium arcu porta vel. Aliquam egestas massa non facilisis vulputate. Fusce viverra sit amet ligula quis lobortis. Etiam vulputate augue non nulla egestas commodo. Pellentesque pellentesque, nulla a efficitur pretium, turpis dolor convallis nibh, in pulvinar massa tellus sed felis. Fusce ac libero ac tellus vehicula tempus.
Donec facilisis, magna ac sagittis suscipit, libero lacus ultricies nibh, et ultrices risus tortor eget mauris. Aliquam sit amet cursus elit. Proin bibendum enim erat, ac aliquet elit dignissim a. Proin eu dolor dui. Vestibulum sodales risus eget interdum mollis. Curabitur semper tortor ultrices elit scelerisque auctor. Integer gravida consectetur leo, et cursus tellus faucibus consectetur. Phasellus non massa nec sem fermentum viverra vel quis risus. Donec lobortis tempor metus. Cras dapibus nulla semper sapien lobortis tempus. Quisque suscipit at nulla sed dictum. Duis aliquam enim nec lorem tristique, quis mattis ante vestibulum.
Sed sit amet sem nunc. Vivamus ornare sapien eu ligula efficitur accumsan. Ut in porttitor massa. Mauris pharetra tortor auctor nisl bibendum, nec mollis neque consectetur. Aliquam dictum non velit et bibendum. Aenean interdum magna quis libero gravida volutpat. Sed at dolor a nisl blandit vehicula. Morbi viverra orci justo, ut maximus ligula porta eget. Duis finibus velit odio, sit amet venenatis lectus vestibulum ac. Duis vitae nisl quis nisi suscipit laoreet at at ipsum. Nulla eleifend porttitor ullamcorper.
Sed imperdiet facilisis eleifend. Ut quis quam venenatis enim dictum maximus sit amet id mi. Curabitur a nisl ut lorem ornare viverra. Cras diam justo, consequat ac sapien eget, scelerisque viverra mi. Suspendisse ac justo vel lacus malesuada vestibulum et eget elit. Aliquam pulvinar ultricies ipsum. Pellentesque nisi ligula, efficitur ut urna vel, efficitur maximus augue. Integer placerat a nibh vitae scelerisque.
Nam non lectus risus. Aliquam a diam a justo ultrices vestibulum ut ac erat. Mauris efficitur, neque eget euismod bibendum, orci turpis suscipit turpis, ut finibus leo risus nec est. Vestibulum imperdiet arcu in hendrerit molestie. Etiam eget nunc libero. Donec viverra mauris a condimentum cursus. Sed tortor risus, porta ac lacus quis, placerat aliquam nibh. Donec lorem elit, congue at velit congue, ullamcorper ullamcorper lacus. Sed pretium sit amet ipsum tincidunt tempus. Nullam eu tempus nulla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
}
\newpage
After
\end{document}
```

---

**First attempt**

Something like this the idea is to detect a page that only has footnotes and in that case don't output it run an extra internal `\output` with a special output penalty so that you can detect it, this has maximum `\vsize` so that it collects all of the potentially split footnote so that it can be re-inserted.

Notes

1) I added some numbers so that I could check the text was being re-constituted in the right order.

2) Currently as I only detect the marker penalty in a normal output routine setup any trailing split insertion gets lost at the clearpage at end of document that's probably fixable but here I just added a normal third page which picks up the end of the footnote.

3) something is amiss with the interline spacing in the reconstituted footnote.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newbox\zzz
\makeatletter

\output {%
\ifnum\outputpenalty=-10123
\setbox\z@\box\@cclv
\insert\footins{\offinterlineskip\unvbox\footins}%
\global\vsize\textheight
\else
\ifdim\wd\@cclv=\z@
\setbox\z@\box\@cclv
\global\vsize\maxdimen
\null\penalty-10123
\else
  \let \par \@@par
  \ifnum \outputpenalty<-\@M
    \@specialoutput
  \else
    \@makecol
    \@opcol
    \@startcolumn
    \@whilesw \if@fcolmade \fi
      {%
       \@opcol\@startcolumn}%
  \fi
  \ifnum \outputpenalty>-\@Miv
    \ifdim \@colroom<1.5\baselineskip
      \ifdim \@colroom<\textheight
        \@latex@warning@no@line {Text page \thepage\space
                               contains only floats}%
        \@emptycol
      \else
        \global \vsize \@colroom
      \fi
    \else
      \global \vsize \@colroom
    \fi
  \else
    \global \vsize \maxdimen
  \fi
\fi
\fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
Before\footnote{\textbf{1} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In sit amet feugiat magna, vitae rutrum magna. Nam viverra lacus nec augue sodales, sed imperdiet quam egestas. Maecenas sed tellus in leo pellentesque ornare gravida vitae odio. Duis tristique suscipit porttitor. Nam vel ante lorem. Proin ornare euismod metus, nec auctor nisl pharetra eget. Curabitur fringilla erat ut ex varius, eget sagittis nunc pretium. Donec pulvinar cursus arcu non finibus. Pellentesque ut lorem et justo eleifend eleifend.
\textbf{2} Pellentesque ac quam sed dolor maximus laoreet non at turpis. Mauris egestas leo elit. Morbi non venenatis ipsum. Sed id odio pulvinar, malesuada purus pharetra, viverra arcu. Mauris consectetur fermentum hendrerit. Nulla lacus arcu, dictum eu vehicula vitae, dignissim interdum risus. Donec convallis dolor ac sem faucibus, vitae porttitor neque lobortis. Pellentesque at tempor eros. Phasellus eget fringilla tellus, posuere porta enim. Sed pellentesque dolor ac feugiat feugiat. Nullam tempus lacus ut eros sagittis consectetur.
\textbf{3} Cras rhoncus congue arcu, fringilla fringilla lorem rutrum viverra. Proin ultrices, felis vel efficitur gravida, lectus lectus suscipit lorem, nec condimentum risus odio quis lacus. Aliquam sem dolor, semper eget fringilla et, pellentesque ac nisl. Ut vitae finibus justo. Nulla lobortis semper tellus eget tempor. Phasellus rutrum ornare lacus a pulvinar. Proin sed odio in sem tincidunt convallis et id leo. Duis nec porta sapien. Sed lacinia erat non mauris fermentum, ac vulputate felis facilisis. Praesent pellentesque laoreet nulla ac convallis. Phasellus sed congue elit, in fermentum est. Nam nisl diam, suscipit eget eleifend nec, lacinia in ipsum. Etiam quis augue ut felis semper gravida vel eget ligula. Quisque quis leo quis leo blandit consequat. Fusce vel sapien ut urna varius tincidunt et eu ipsum.
\textbf{4} Phasellus in tortor at diam euismod dignissim vitae in ex. Maecenas vestibulum rutrum enim, ut convallis felis accumsan vitae. Aenean id erat at nibh pretium aliquet sed ut purus. Nulla vel justo euismod, molestie metus nec, luctus urna. Fusce fermentum mattis enim eu viverra. Donec convallis, tellus ac congue pharetra, neque neque faucibus mi, sed scelerisque orci velit sit amet nisl. Sed eleifend eu eros quis blandit.
\textbf{5} Etiam rhoncus rutrum ante eu ultricies. Morbi arcu dui, aliquet eu ante at, elementum aliquet tellus. Sed eget sodales lacus. Etiam venenatis sollicitudin mi, quis egestas mauris vulputate ut. Maecenas lobortis erat a lacus congue bibendum. Vestibulum interdum semper orci, sit amet mattis dui egestas non. Integer malesuada risus ut vehicula viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Curabitur maximus eget dui sed bibendum. Phasellus tristique arcu at metus rhoncus pretium.
\textbf{6} Proin volutpat felis lobortis massa semper, ut efficitur est commodo. Nam dapibus metus vitae finibus hendrerit. Maecenas sit amet malesuada libero. Duis sed nisl vitae urna blandit placerat a ac eros. In pellentesque porttitor lacus sit amet mollis. Nulla facilisi. Aenean scelerisque neque pretium orci egestas, vel iaculis dolor ullamcorper.
\textbf{7} Fusce hendrerit blandit ipsum quis scelerisque. Quisque ac tincidunt eros, vitae mattis diam. Nunc varius fringilla nisl, nec cursus erat hendrerit nec. Pellentesque volutpat lacus lectus, sed suscipit sem lacinia id. Nulla eget varius ex. Nullam ac justo ac nisi molestie mattis. Nunc a consectetur quam. Donec sit amet lacus massa.
\textbf{8} Quisque commodo nunc a hendrerit pretium. Donec rhoncus, eros a ullamcorper blandit, mauris tellus tincidunt lacus, et dictum ligula risus at orci. In ornare, mauris vel efficitur facilisis, velit elit laoreet ante, et dignissim magna eros in ex. Nam varius hendrerit tempor. Maecenas quis augue augue. Integer bibendum, orci a sagittis dignissim, elit tortor fermentum augue, sed gravida magna ligula sed nisi. Cras suscipit justo nunc, eu mattis turpis vulputate at. Nulla facilisi. Nunc rutrum, enim non laoreet pellentesque, quam neque posuere tortor, nec placerat tellus est id purus. Aenean velit tellus, placerat maximus pellentesque in, viverra sit amet nunc. Donec aliquam nunc ligula, eget aliquam lorem mattis sit amet. Pellentesque in ultrices nisi. Donec iaculis dictum auctor. Aenean nulla sapien, sodales vel pharetra a, varius sit amet elit.
\textbf{9} Maecenas et sagittis mauris. Donec nec urna nulla. Donec diam urna, bibendum sit amet sapien convallis, commodo sollicitudin mauris. Etiam et malesuada justo. In molestie tortor at massa tempor, vitae imperdiet neque sollicitudin. Donec id ultricies lectus, nec interdum nibh. Donec porttitor diam a nibh luctus scelerisque. Vestibulum tortor dolor, consectetur vitae metus sed, suscipit pulvinar lacus. Fusce id posuere diam. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec malesuada, nisl ac dapibus volutpat, elit turpis imperdiet urna, eget dictum ipsum elit ac felis. Nunc et suscipit nulla. Nunc tristique varius elementum. In consequat pharetra suscipit. Suspendisse potenti.
\textbf{10} Quisque tincidunt risus eros, in congue nunc efficitur in. Etiam lobortis lectus et justo rhoncus, sit amet aliquam lorem rhoncus. In molestie, turpis eget dapibus hendrerit, turpis ipsum mattis sem, at finibus lectus odio sed arcu. Cras suscipit lacinia felis nec lobortis. Etiam non tempor nulla. Integer porttitor augue leo, at cursus mi sodales nec. Nulla facilisi. Praesent nulla purus, ultricies non libero et, condimentum porta turpis. Vestibulum tincidunt, magna et consequat viverra, arcu neque tristique ipsum, sed tincidunt nisi neque non mi.
\textbf{11} Etiam sit amet sagittis magna, at faucibus nunc. Cras metus tortor, egestas et enim sit amet, pellentesque dictum mi. Nullam ultricies lorem non accumsan condimentum. Nulla sed dignissim augue. Vestibulum ornare ac mi vel efficitur. In nec leo elit. Aliquam sit amet ipsum ac metus semper consectetur. Etiam efficitur nisi in maximus convallis. Sed ac pretium eros, consectetur tincidunt nisl.
\textbf{12} Nulla tincidunt malesuada odio eu posuere. Donec varius lacus ut tellus commodo porta. Nam convallis dui id tortor tristique, ut scelerisque lacus fringilla. Praesent non purus sed nisi auctor ornare quis sit amet ante. Praesent sit amet gravida est, at pellentesque ligula. Integer aliquam tempor ligula. Suspendisse blandit fermentum leo, quis posuere eros vulputate nec. Aliquam erat volutpat. In in orci vestibulum, feugiat est at, suscipit leo.
\textbf{13} Fusce ultrices nisl quis sapien cursus, mattis mattis mi sodales. Morbi pulvinar, enim et facilisis tristique, ligula nisl iaculis purus, sit amet euismod ex urna nec neque. Praesent id velit elementum, finibus nisl quis, sollicitudin urna. Nunc porta auctor elit, id pulvinar mauris efficitur et. Morbi quis erat sed metus sagittis mattis vel ut erat. Donec eget aliquet sem, ac dictum purus. Donec varius risus et tortor pharetra, sed tincidunt erat viverra. Pellentesque accumsan dui ac rutrum dictum.
\textbf{14} Phasellus aliquam lorem sit amet ex tempor aliquet. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis sit amet faucibus sem, rhoncus semper lacus. Sed a eros diam. Curabitur sit amet ante elementum, suscipit tortor vitae, malesuada mi. Sed ac gravida mi. Mauris mollis nunc id lectus cursus, vel ornare justo aliquam. Pellentesque sed est metus. Nulla laoreet, augue in maximus accumsan, ante est gravida nisl, quis dignissim quam est scelerisque sem. Morbi ac purus metus. Duis ut tellus purus. Nunc at nisi luctus, pharetra nisi ac, vulputate enim. Praesent commodo finibus malesuada. Praesent non tortor fermentum, volutpat magna id, hendrerit tortor. In dolor lacus, imperdiet sit amet aliquam nec, ultrices sed sem.
\textbf{15} Pellentesque quis lectus vitae elit rhoncus efficitur. Quisque tristique id tortor quis euismod. Etiam vitae neque quis quam feugiat porta at sit amet leo. Nam id leo vestibulum libero eleifend facilisis quis et orci. Vivamus vitae magna eu nibh facilisis auctor vitae sed purus. Curabitur a velit quis erat ullamcorper venenatis vitae non sem. Cras bibendum magna nec tellus convallis, in tincidunt justo auctor. Curabitur nec sem nibh. Vestibulum rhoncus laoreet nisi, sit amet rutrum lectus dictum id. Sed leo neque, iaculis viverra porta at, rhoncus eu felis. Mauris ornare arcu sit amet augue sagittis semper. Suspendisse egestas blandit lorem in posuere. Nam volutpat dolor at mauris malesuada, eget egestas orci gravida. Suspendisse dapibus felis sit amet sapien auctor, a sagittis ante sollicitudin. Vivamus a orci mollis, auctor lectus et, sodales nunc. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
\textbf{16} Donec in nunc luctus, iaculis sem id, tincidunt lorem. Donec congue consectetur ex, nec pretium arcu porta vel. Aliquam egestas massa non facilisis vulputate. Fusce viverra sit amet ligula quis lobortis. Etiam vulputate augue non nulla egestas commodo. Pellentesque pellentesque, nulla a efficitur pretium, turpis dolor convallis nibh, in pulvinar massa tellus sed felis. Fusce ac libero ac tellus vehicula tempus.
\textbf{17} Donec facilisis, magna ac sagittis suscipit, libero lacus ultricies nibh, et ultrices risus tortor eget mauris. Aliquam sit amet cursus elit. Proin bibendum enim erat, ac aliquet elit dignissim a. Proin eu dolor dui. Vestibulum sodales risus eget interdum mollis. Curabitur semper tortor ultrices elit scelerisque auctor. Integer gravida consectetur leo, et cursus tellus faucibus consectetur. Phasellus non massa nec sem fermentum viverra vel quis risus. Donec lobortis tempor metus. Cras dapibus nulla semper sapien lobortis tempus. Quisque suscipit at nulla sed dictum. Duis aliquam enim nec lorem tristique, quis mattis ante vestibulum.
\textbf{18} Sed sit amet sem nunc. Vivamus ornare sapien eu ligula efficitur accumsan. Ut in porttitor massa. Mauris pharetra tortor auctor nisl bibendum, nec mollis neque consectetur. Aliquam dictum non velit et bibendum. Aenean interdum magna quis libero gravida volutpat. Sed at dolor a nisl blandit vehicula. Morbi viverra orci justo, ut maximus ligula porta eget. Duis finibus velit odio, sit amet venenatis lectus vestibulum ac. Duis vitae nisl quis nisi suscipit laoreet at at ipsum. Nulla eleifend porttitor ullamcorper.
\textbf{19} Sed imperdiet facilisis eleifend. Ut quis quam venenatis enim dictum maximus sit amet id mi. Curabitur a nisl ut lorem ornare viverra. Cras diam justo, consequat ac sapien eget, scelerisque viverra mi. Suspendisse ac justo vel lacus malesuada vestibulum et eget elit. Aliquam pulvinar ultricies ipsum. Pellentesque nisi ligula, efficitur ut urna vel, efficitur maximus augue. Integer placerat a nibh vitae scelerisque.
\textbf{20} Nam non lectus risus. Aliquam a diam a justo ultrices vestibulum ut ac erat. Mauris efficitur, neque eget euismod bibendum, orci turpis suscipit turpis, ut finibus leo risus nec est. Vestibulum imperdiet arcu in hendrerit molestie. Etiam eget nunc libero. Donec viverra mauris a condimentum cursus. Sed tortor risus, porta ac lacus quis, placerat aliquam nibh. Donec lorem elit, congue at velit congue, ullamcorper ullamcorper lacus. Sed pretium sit amet ipsum tincidunt tempus. Nullam eu tempus nulla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
}
\newpage
After
\newpage
even more After
\end{document}
```

Comment: many thank. I will try with that. Indeed, you are right: we need number to check (or real text, that is what I do in my real test)

Comment: there is also problem with order. See the "faucibus" at the end of one paragraph...

Comment: I think, but I am not sur, that the "long" part of the notes are inserted AFTER the last long part.

Comment: @Maïeul see update

Comment: @Maïeul oh no my update is same as touhami's answer. You should give the bounty there. that _is_ the answer.

Comment: the problem is, for my case, ita est eledpar, I need to have a footins which is not moved. Because user can define it as he want. For example it could want to have only half page with note.

Comment: see my contrainst one Not modify the space kept for note.

Comment: @Maïeul It isn't modifying the space, just the way Tex uses the space in the calculation. latex doesn't reset \dimen\footins from the value it got in plain (where it is less than \vsize) this means in the default settings for article it is greater then \vsize. tex never allocates that much space to footnotes (they never go off the page) but because it is _set_ that way it allows a full page of notes. If you set the value to any value > \textwidth it makes no difference but to prevent a full page of split footnote setting it to a fraction less than \vsize is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Maïeul if the user has set \dimen\footins don't change it, you only need to make sure the value is not > \textheight

Comment: @Maïeul well whether not not you can use it in eledpar you should give the bounty to the other answer. You've lost the points in any case and the only part of my answer that's different doesn't fully work (and is I have decided not the right approach) so shame to let them go to waste:-)

Comment: Yes, I did, but that is not a valid answer... Or i don't understand well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21421/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-maieul).